# When to post on Cross Validated over Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

So, I notice that a lot of statistics (in particular, R-related) questions get posted (and answered) on Stack Overflow, rather than [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about).

Given that the field of modern statistics is unabashed about its reliance on computing, what is a clear-cut guideline for asking a question on one over the other?

Comment: There is some overlap.  That is not uncommon amoungst SO and the other related sites that have on-topic programming questions.  The general guideline is to ask where you think you'll get a better answer.  SO is usually a larger audience, but with more diverse knowledge/skills.  CV will have a smaller audience but probably more direct experience.  If you can't choose, pick the smaller site.

Comment: Anything and everything gets posted on SO. If you know a question to be on topic somewhere else (even if it is also on topic for SO), ask it there instead. There are certainly some questions only on topic for [stats.se] and some stats questions only on topic for [so], but I don't really know much about that.

Comment: It's acceptable on both sites. Generally, if your question concerns stats more than programming, use Cross Validated. If it's a programming question more than a stats question, use Stack Overflow.

Comment: In each question you should place some tags (key-words). I think that an useful way to decide is to see if the tags you want to place are offered by the corresponding site or/and how many times these tags are used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the on-topic CV list [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

The current guideline for programming questions is:

> There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on our sister sites. If your question is about
>
> Programming, ask on Stack Overflow. If the language is statistically oriented (such as R, SAS, Stata, SPSS, etc.), then decide based on the nature of your question: if it needs statistical expertise to understand or answer, ask it here;...

Usually, questions tagged with statistical software are expected to have other tags associated in the thread. For example, CV tag [software](/questions/tagged/software) excerpt says the following:

> Make sure your question is related to STATISTICS, MACHINE LEARNING, or DATA ANALYSIS and is not solely about programming, support, or bugs. Include additional tags referring to the statistical issues involved.

Recently, some CV meta threads have discussed the possibility to make the guidelines even more clearer about on topic and off-topic programming related questions there:

[Defining clearer house rules on software-related questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/what-does-crossvalidated-aim-to-be-who-is-it-for)

and

[What does CrossValidated aim to be, who is it for?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1780/defining-clearer-house-rules-on-software-related-questions/1781#1781)